# Problem with the cursor in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have a problem in that I can't edit any code in the program. When I try, it looks like I'm in "insert" mode, with a block cursor.

I can't delete anything or write anything. What could it be? And how do I fix it? (I am on a MacBook Pro.)

Comment: Check if you have installed VIM extension in your VS code ? Then delete or uninstall it. it will solve your problem.

Comment: I think you have please update your vs code software

Comment: So that solve your problem

Answer (score 6):

happens when you install vim extension, either remove it and restart the vscode or learn vim tldr: press i for insert mode and write